# Remove all unnecessary spaces and a certain punctuation

Tags: regex, r

Consider the following string

```
str1 <- "  say    wut      ??   "
```

I want to remove all additional spaces between words and `??` and trim the whole thing

So the following works perfectly

```
gsub("(^ *)|( +(?= ))|( $)", "", str1, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "say wut ??"
```

Now, if I have the following string

```
str2 <- "[ ] say[]    wut      ??  [] "
```

And I want to reach the previous result (I *don't* want to remove all punctuation except `??`, because in real life I have other punctuation too that I want to keep. In other words, I just want to remove `[]` and the unnecessary spaces)

So I've tried the following, but I've got my leading spaces back

```
gsub("\\]|\\[|(^ *)|( +(?= ))|( $)", "", str2, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "  say wut ?? "
```

Interestingly (or not), when reversing the regex order, everything messes up even more

```
gsub("(^ *)|\\]|\\[|( +(?= ))|( $)", "", str2, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "[  say wut ?? "
```

---

Edit: It seems that I wasn't clear enough, but I'm looking for a *clean regex* solution. I'm well aware that you can do practically *anything* in several steps (and I'm already doing so), but this is not what I'm looking for.

This is what I was using until now (two steps solution):

```
gsub("(^ *)|( +(?= ))|( $)", "", gsub("\\]|\\[", "", x), perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem with a *single* `gsub` and the following regex.

```
x <- c('  say    wut      ??   ', 
       '[ ] say[]    wut      ??  [] ', 
       '[ ] say[] wut ?? [] ',
       '[say ] wut ??')

gsub("^[[\\] ]+|[[\\] ]+$|[[\\]]| +([[\\]]+)?(?= )", "", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "say wut ??" "say wut ??" "say wut ??" "say wut ??"
```

---

*How it works?*

This regex looks for 4 different patterns that are combined with logical *or* (`"|"`):

- `"^[[\\] ]"`: The `"^"` indicates the beginning of the string. The brackets are used to match any of the specified characters, i.e., `"["`, `"]"`, and `" "`. Note that I don't need to escape `"["` in brackets. The `"+"` indicates one or multiple matches.
- `"[[\\] ]+$"`: Similar to the first pattern, but `"$"` indicates the end of the string.
- `"[[\\]]"`: One of `"["` or `"]"`.
- `" +([[\\]]+)?(?= )"`: One or multiple spaces (`" +"`), optionally (`"?"`) followed by one or more occurrences of `"["` or `"]"`, followed by a space (`"(?= )"`).

Comment: It seems like it still will leave an additional space in `x <-'[say ] wut ??'`

Answer (score 4):

@DavidArenburg, at first I had my head wrapped around the main point of the question being stated:

> "I want to remove all additional spaces between **words** and `??` and trim the whole thing"

However, the reason your expressions did not do what you expected and I see now is because you were not accounting for spaces preceding or between the bracket characters with the way you were using alternation, which is why I stated you would need cascading calls to do this. One to remove the spaces then the bracket characters.

And then realized the logic of "leading/trailing bracket characters and spaces" being included is what you needed.

```
x <- c('  say    wut      ??   ', 
       '[ ] say[]    wut      ??  [] ', 
       '[ ] say[] wut ?? [] ',
       '[say ] wut ??',
       '   say  ]  [ wut ?? ]')

gsub('^([[\\] ]+)|([[\\]]+)| +(?2)?(?= )|(?1)$', '', x, perl=T)
# [1] "say wut ??" "say wut ??" "say wut ??" "say wut ??" "say wut ??"
```

Comment: It seems like it still will leave an additional space in `x <-'[say ]  wut      ??'` Seems like the double `gsub` is still the best answer

Answer (score 2):

This would work,

```
> x <- "[ ] say[]    wut      ??  [] "
> gsub("^\\s*\\[?\\s*\\]?\\s*|\\s*\\[?\\s*\\]?\\s*$|\\[?\\s*\\]?\\s*(?=\\s)", "", x, perl=T)
[1] "say wut ??"
```

Comment: This solution keeps the white spaces in the beginning and end if x = str1

Comment: If: x <- "  say    wut      ??   ", then your solution results: " say wut ?? " instead of "say wut ??"

Comment: This also won't work for `x <- "[ ] say  []wut      ??  [] "`

Answer (score 2):

This is more an answer for future searchers in that it gives the desired output but not by giving a regex.  The `qdapRegex` package has the `rm_square` function that will remove the square braces.  The function also defaults to clean up white spaces so it akes this task pretty easy:

```
x <- c('  say    wut      ??   ', '[ ] say[]    wut      ??  [] ', '[ ] say[] wut ?? [] ')

library(qdapRegex)
rm_square(x)

## [1] "say wut ??" "say wut ??" "say wut ??"
```

Comment: That is absolutely awesome, what exactly give you the idea of creating this strange function :)?

Comment: It's part of a family of functions that remove brackets, see `?rm_square`.  It is useful for removing brackets and all info in between then.

Comment: Now that I've tested it a bit, I found out that it removes what inside brackets too (not only the brackets). I.e., something like `x <-'[say ]  wut      ??'` won't give me the desired result

Comment: Yeah, this worked for the data you provided but maybe now you see the usefulness of the function moreso.

Answer (score 1):

How about the regex

```
[\s\[\]]+
```

the replace string is space ()

`gsub("[]\s\[\]]+", " ", str2, perl = TRUE)`

will produce

`" say wut ?? "`

see how it matches http://regex101.com/r/eJ4rY5/2

If the starting and trailing spaces to be removed

`(^\s|\s$)` 
would be usefull

`gsub("(^\s|\s$)", "", " say wut ?? ", perl = TRUE)`

would give

`"say wut ??"`

Comment: Not working: Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""[]\s"

Comment: Neither of these solves my problem sorry. In R you need to escape meta-characters with double back slash, i.e., instead of `\s` it should be `\\s` and etc

Comment: Gave you (+1) for partial solution with `"[]\\s\\[\\]]+`

Comment: Not all of it. Just partially

Comment: @DavidArenburg apart from the leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Using a second `gsub` may solve the problem right?